# How do I open an excel file in Excel 365 (app) in write protected mode?

Tags: microsoft-excel

It was easy with the desktop version of excel (e.g. 2016) by creating a short cut to the Excel file in question and the following in the short cut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /r "D:\excelfile.xlsx"
```

Since Office switched to "Apps", this is no longer possible. Of course I could open the file with another program or set the file "read only" or write a script to do it for me, which seems rather "complicated". Is there an easy work around?

Comment: thanks but I don't want to use "office online" within the browser, that is not what I'm asking about (I want to use the locally installed version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand this is not possible. It's necessary to install the "desktop version"  in order for the shortcut to work.

I downloaded it by starting the "Office App" and logging in via my 365 account credentials and choosing "other installations" from the "install button" (sorry for the German screenshot):

[image]

Then it still works fine with my current Office 365 Version 1910. In my case the correct shortcut is: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /r "D:\excelfile.xlsx"`